# JS regex to check a string is number of char long, between a min and max limit, not counting spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, range

**Update - The Use-Case**: this is for a custom "pattern"-like attribute on a Custom Element. The custom attribute/accessor takes any regex - I've already coded this part. I need this particular regex for my own use, and given I only have an attribute value (a string) to work with, and it's expecting a regex, I must have the regex perform all required functions.

**Update 2**: look folks, if you can think of a way to not use a regex with an attribute (validate="") that requires a regex string, then good luck. That's my constraint, it's what I'm dealing with. It's a valid question, and having drive-by downvoters doesn't change that, or help. Grow up, seriously.

Basically, I need a regex that checks a string for a length that fits a provided min and max range, without counting any spaces in the string. For example:

```
var foo = ' a 1 b 2 - _ ';
```

In the variable `foo` above, there are 6 non-space characters, which given their total count would fit a range of 3-6, 5-7, 6-10, etc. I need a way of tallying all those non-space chars and checking they fit in a range.

**Note**: *I cannot accept answers that say "First, remove spaces from the string with replace()", or anything like that - it must be all done in the regex.*

Comment: you can apply `(\S)` and count the groups

Comment: `var r = ' a 1 b 2 - _ '.match(/\S/g).length`

Comment: @hwnd - given the constraints, detailed above, I cannot do operations outside the regex, like check a property, etc. It's not a system hard-bound to range checking, that's just one case I need and must fit it in the constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a pure regex solution, I suggest this:

```
function ok(text) {
  return text.match(/^\s*(\S\s*){3,7}$/);
}
```

Replace 3 and 7 with the min and max, respectively.

Comment: Sometimes the right answers are the "wrong" approaches .. but it does meet the OPs stated requirements.

Comment: @user2864740: This is unquestionably the wrong approach to "length should be X to Y non-whitespace characters". It may be the right answer to this question, though. I don't know the OP's purpose.

Comment: The purpose is a custom "pattern"-like attribute, thus only a string is allowed, and it must perform the actions necessary to check this and any other regex check. (I happen to need the length range of non-space chars)

Comment: @Charles I believe this works. I'm going to test it a bunch tomorrow morning, and if it works, I'll accept your answer. Thank you for trying to help - I can't change my constraints, so I appreciate the effort you made to fit this all into the regex as I asked!

Comment: @Charles this works! Thank you. One note, it can be simplified a bit like this: `/^ *(\S *){3,7}$/`. (Maybe you want to update your answer with this addition?)

Answer (score 0):

Just count them :

```
var foo = ' a 1 b 2 - _ ';
var count = foo.match(/\s[0-9a-zA-Z-_\s]/g).length;
```

Comment: `\s` can be problematic here as it would fail on `'a 1 b 2 - _'`; also it is clearly wrong to include it in the character class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simplify the answer Charles provided by getting rid of the `\s` occurrences and implying them with spaces:

```
var text = 'foo bar';  
text.match(/^ *(\S *){3,7}$/);
// this would validate the string is between 3 and 7
// characters long, after trimming out spaces or line breaks
```

*Note: I asked Charles to update his answer before posting this, I just want to make sure folks viewing the question in the future see the simplest expression possible :)*